# Scala: Does == default to equals?

Tags: scala, equality

I'm reading through Programming in Scala.  It says:

> You can redefine the behavior of `==` for new types by overriding the `equals` method, which is always inherited from class `Any`. The inherited `equals`, which takes effect unless overridden, is object identity, as is the case in Java. So `equals` (and with it, `==`) is by default the same as `eq`, but you can change its behavior by overriding the `equals` method in the classes you define. It is not possible to override `==` directly, as it is defined as a final method in class `Any`. That is, Scala treats `==` as if was defined as follows in class `Any`:
>
> ```
> final def == (that: Any): Boolean = 
>   if (null eq this) (null eq that) else (this equals that)
> ```

But this isn't jibing with what I'm seeing in scala 2.9.1, where it seems like:

- `==` doesn't seem to default to `equals`
- I can override `==` directly (without complaint from the compiler, no `override` needed).

So it seems to me like either:

- I'm doing it wrong - [this definition of `Rational`](https://gist.github.com/2185095) gives

  ```
  % scala                                                                   
  Welcome to Scala version 2.9.1.final (Java HotSpot(TM) 64-Bit Server VM, Java 1.6.0_29).
  Type in expressions to have them evaluated.
  Type :help for more information.

  scala> Rational(1) == Rational(1)
  res0: Boolean = false

  scala> Rational(1) equals Rational(1)
  res1: Boolean = true
  ```
- or I'm reading an out of date version of the book, and things have changed.

What's going on?

Answer (score 21, accepted):

You are making a very understandable mistake--you are trying to write a type-safe equals (i.e. `def equals(r: Rational)`) instead of a generic equals (i.e. `override def equals(a: Any)`).

So instead of overriding `equals`--note that you don't need the `override` keyword!--you are creating another method by overloading the type parameters, and then having *two* equals methods, one which takes `Rational` and one which takes `Any`.  Same thing with `==`; only the `Any`-parameterized method cannot be overridden.

To get the behavior consistent with Java (and the Scala library), you'd need to rewrite equals as something like

```
override def equals(a: Any) = a match {
  case r: Rational => numer == r.numer && denom == r.demon
  case _ => false
}
```

Comment: Awesome. This bites me every time I return to JVM land. I'll learn it sooner or later.  Is there anyway I can drop the `a match` and just assign `equals` an anonymous function? `override def equals : Any => Boolean = { case r : Rational /* ... */ }` doesn't quite work...

Comment: @rampion - No, you have to match the type signature exactly.  `equals: Any=>Boolean` means that it returns a function (i.e. an instance of a `Function1[Any,Boolean]` class).  Even though this is conceptually equivalent in some sense, it is not the exact same method, so it won't work.