# Can this be null in Scala?

Tags: scala, null, this

I just read [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9853645/) and stumbled upon the following quote:

> Scala treats `==` as if it were defined as follows in class `Any`:
>
> ```
> final def == (that: Any): Boolean = 
>   if (null eq this) (null eq that) else (this equals that)
> ```

The `(null eq this)` part made me wonder: Is it actually possible to call methods on null pointers? Can `this` be `null` in Scala?

Comment: You are confusing the abstraction with the implementation. Abstractly, one can call methods on `null`, such as `==`. The implementation on the JVM, obviously, does not invoke methods on a null pointer.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Check out the [Scala language specification](http://www.scala-lang.org/docu/files/ScalaReference.pdf), namely *6.3 The Null Value* chapter:

> The null value is of type `scala.Null`, and is thus compatible with every reference
>   type. It denotes a reference value which refers to a special **“null”** object. This object
>   implements methods in class `scala.AnyRef` as follows:
>
> • `eq(x)` and `==(x)` return true if the argument `x` is also the “null” object.
>
> • `ne(x)` and `!=(x)` return true if the argument `x` is not also the “null” object.

This means that semantically when you compare something with `null` literal or `null` literal with something you are actually referring to method of a special [`scala.Null`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Null.html) class. Treat `null` literal as a shorthand for that class.

Of course at the implementation level it is optimized and *ordinary* `null` is used.

Answer (score 3):

`null` is the only instance of [`Null`](http://www.scala-lang.org/api/current/scala/Null.html) class and it's a valid object. `Null` is a subtype of all reference types.

Answer (score 1):

I'm pretty new to Scala, but the only way I see that as being possible is due to the fact that "null" itself is an instance of Null, and not exactly a special value like "null" in Java.

http://blog.sanaulla.info/2009/07/12/nothingness/

This article helped me understand this a bit better.