# Why is this test not tautological?

Tags: unit-testing, null, this

This is not about explicit code, so apologies if it should have been posted elsewhere. It is, however, solidly within the domain of testing, which I assume you guys to be right at home in.

I'm reading the provocatively titled paper ["Why Most Unit Testing is Waste"](http://rbcs-us.com/documents/Why-Most-Unit-Testing-is-Waste.pdf) (21 pages) and came across this passage:

> The third tests to throw away the tautological ones. [...] Testing for  `this` being non-null on entry to a method is, by the way, not a tautological test — and can be very informative [...]

This really piqued my curiosity -- why would `this` *ever* be null *on purpose*? *How* would you even write such code?

*Edit:* Thank you Daniel! I don't know much C(/++/#) but my initial (Java-centric) thought was that **no, it's not possible**, and I seem to be right, with reference to your 2nd comment that *"If you're using this, then you're in the instance so this [can't be] null."*

Comment: [Checking if this is NULL in C++](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844005/checking-if-this-is-null)

Comment: [Can "this" ever be null in Java?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789528/can-this-ever-be-null-in-java)

Comment: [Can "this" ever be null in JavaScript?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739806/can-this-ever-be-null-in-javascript)

Comment: [Can this be null in Scala?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072645/can-this-be-null-in-scala)

Comment: [Within a C# instance method, can 'this' ever be null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5055068/within-a-c-sharp-instance-method-can-this-ever-be-null) / [Why check this != null?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3143498/why-check-this-null)

Comment: @DanielDaranas, thank you so much! I'd accept your answers if you'd let me.

Comment: I didn't post the links to related questions as an answer because they would not constitute an answer. I didn't vote your question as duplicate, either, because your question does not specify a language and so it does not seem an exact duplicate of any of the related questions. I did post them, though, as comments, because I thought they could be of interest.

Comment: You could easily compile all those comments into table-form (with "yes" "no" flags) which would make a very good generic answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

- [Can "this" ever be null in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3789528/can-this-ever-be-null-in-java) - No, it can't.
- [Can "this" ever be null in JavaScript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9739806/can-this-ever-be-null-in-javascript) - No, it can't.
- [Can "this" ever be null in C++?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1844005/checking-if-this-is-null) - Not in standard C++, but it might in certain cases with VC++ and MFC.
- [Can "this" ever be null in Scala?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10072645/can-this-be-null-in-scala) - (I'm unsure how to interpret that post's answers.)
- [Can "this" ever be null in Javascript?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39272637/why-is-this-test-not-tautological#comment67611817_40171921) - Yes, it can, in strict mode.

Credit goes to @DanielDaranas.

Comment: Javascript: [*Yes, it can,*](http://bcgavel.com/wp-content/uploads/2015/04/tumblr_md3p0xrgqy1r0z99do1_500.jpg) in strict mode…